# chrome issue: images displayed incorrectly

Tags: css, list, google-chrome

i have been researching and trying for a while now but still run into the same problem:

i am running tests for my new website which seems to work fine across a majority of browsers, but not with chrome on some smartphones. it is about this site:
http://www.beatekoerner.com/new/works.html

the images of the gallery are arranged with "display:inline" (in the "image"-class) and are displayed correctly in firefox.

in chrome, however, the page tends to look like this:
http://www.beatekoerner.com/work/11025027_10205551999857433_2043483876_o.jpg

this varies according to smartphone (it looks different on mine, the screenshot is of a friend's). the strangest thing is that it seems possible to "fix" the bug by clicking the link again, but NOT with reloading the page. i was not able to reproduce this behaviour with a forced reload.

i got rid of the subnav in the meantime (wall/drawing etc), so please ignore that.

the list in html:

```
  <div id="maintext" class="tiles">
  <div class="image"><a href="works/time.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/time.jpg"><h2>time</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/shame.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/shame.jpg"><h2>shame</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/letters.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/letters.jpg"><h2>letters</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/matter.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/matter.jpg"><h2>a matter of time</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/pilesmountains.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/pilesmountains.jpg"><h2>piles and mountains</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/spring.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/spring.jpg"><h2>spring</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/radical.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/pileportraits.jpg"><h2>radical archaeologies</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/organ.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/organ.jpg"><h2>organ</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/pilestudy.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/pilestudy.jpg"><h2>pile (study)</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/older.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/older.jpg"><h2>older presences</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/fliegenklatsche.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/hellenaechte.jpg"><h2>works for<br/> "fliegenklatsche" magazine</h2></a></div>  
  <div class="image"><a href="works/spp.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/spp.jpg"><h2>stop/pause/play<br/>magazine</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/less.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/pile.jpg"><h2>less</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/lecture.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/lecture.jpg"><h2>lecture</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/writing.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/writing.jpg"><h2>writing on the wall</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/weary.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/weary.jpg"><h2>weary</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/corrections.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/corrections.jpg"><h2>corrections</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/assertion.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/assertion.jpg"><h2>behauptung (assertion)</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/100years.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/100years.jpg"><h2>100 years of sleep</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/wryly.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/wryly.jpg"><h2>wryly</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/interchange.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/interchange.jpg"><h2>interchange</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/blink.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/blink.jpg"><h2>blink</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/tram.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/tram.jpg"><h2>tram</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/sadmovie.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/sadmovie.jpg"><h2>sad movie</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/neckarsteinach.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/neckarsteinach.jpg"><h2>neckarsteinach</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/reading.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/reading.jpg"><h2>reading</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/balance.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/balance.jpg"><h2>balance</h2></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href="works/but.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/but.jpg"><h2>aber (but)</h2></a></div>
  </div>
```

with following css definitions:

```
#maintext { 
position: fixed;
top: 180px;
height: 70%;
overflow: auto;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
width: inherit;
z-index: -100; }

#maintext img {
    padding: 10px;
    width: inherit;
    max-width: 600px; }

.tiles {
    text-align: center; }

#maintext.tiles img:hover {
    opacity:0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); 
    outline: none; }
```

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: where are ul and li in your html code?

Comment: you are right, i just used them for the nav (which is not included) - no ul in the maintext div. i will change that.

Comment: i have tried to solve the problem with chrome-workarounds in the meantime, but nothing worked out. does nobody have a solution for this problem?

Comment: As a suggestion set width and height for images, it seems their browsers reserves the space according to dimensions of images. So in first time before complete loading of images, the reserved space is set by a default dimension. in next time after reloading, as the photos are cached in browser, the reserved dimension is equal to real image dimension.

Comment: i have just done that (defined height and width for the "image" class.)

Comment: Current style has only max-width for images but not width. have you updated your style? also current **image class** is set to divs not to images.

Comment: i have different types of images on other pages which use the same css, so i can't apply the same width and height to all images. i renamed the "image" class to "tiles" to make it clearer and defined the height and width for _.tiles img_ ... this does unfortunately not fix the problem.

Comment: please paste **.image** style also. You should be wise about using relative or absolute position or inherited width and height for **.image** class.